# Label does not reduce to an integer constant

Tags: c, switch-statement

error running this  c program  . i'm getting an error like" case label doesnot reduce to an integer constant ". help me  in finding  my errors . i'm a newbie to c, started it a few weeks ago.thanks in advance

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 main()  
  { int a,b,c;
  scanf("%d",&c);
   if (c<5) {
    c==a  ;
   }
   else { c==b;
   }
    switch (c)
   {
    case a:
       printf ("statement1");
       break;
    case b :
       printf(" statement2");
     break;
    }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `c==a;` and `c==b;` statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I corrected your code. Please try it and give me a feedback:

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    scanf("%d",&c);
    if (c<5)
    {
        a = c; //here you will use "=" because you want to a became c
     }
    else
    {
        b = c; //here you will use "=" because you want to b became c
    }
    /*--------IF-------------*/
    if(c==a) //here is a condition. you will use "=="
    {
        printf("statement1");
    }
    if(c==b) //here is a condition. you will use "=="
    {
        printf ("statement2");
    }
    /*--------SWITCH-------------*/
    switch (c)
    {
    case 1: //if c is 1
    case 2: //if c is 2
    case 3: //if c is 3
    case 4: //if c is 4
    printf("statement1"); //"statement1" will appear
    break;
    default: printf("statement2"); //if c >= 5 "statement2" will appear
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you john. your  code worked like charm .  can i have  the same program written using "switch" . that is what i am intended to do .

Comment: So, I see that you marked another answer, but you will can mark my answer again. Any way, for what reply are you waiting?

Comment: what changes u made to my code , i would like to know it.cant figure it out

Comment: I edited the answer. See the comments. Thank you for mark. :)

Comment: john , u have written my program using if else  . but i want switch to be used in the program .

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use switch... anyway, see the edit.

Answer (score 6):

In C, which you seem to be calling `c#` for some reason, **`case` labels must be integer constants**.

> 6.8.4.2-3
>
> The expression of each case label shall be an integer constant
>   expression and no two of the case constant expressions in the same
>   switch statement shall have the same value after  conversion.

Not sure if this is what you want, but you could try:

```
switch (c) {
case 'a':
    break;
case 'b':
    break;
}
```

Otherwise, maybe you want

```
if (c == a)
    /* ... */
else if (c == b)
    /* ... */
else
    /* ... */
```

As side note, you probably want `c=a` instead of `c==a`.

Comment: Looking at the code I think he actually wants to compare c against the variables a and b, so what he should do is replace the switch/case by if/else.

Answer (score 2):

2 problems:

- the values for your case labels need to resolve (ie end up) as integer values for the `case`-statement to work. If you want to drive the statements in the `case` based on the value of variable `c` and comparing it with `a` and `b`, you might want to consider an `if`-statement instead.
- You need to do assignments `=` rather than boolean comparisons `==` here

  ```
  c==a
  ```

  probably want

  ```
  c = a
  ```

  (same applies to `c==b`) -
  *in fact*, are you sure this is the right order, and you don't want the reverse `a = c`? This seems more likely looking at your code segment.

Comment: hii levon.   i corrected my program this way : changed == to = , a=c instead of c=a , same with b . but getting the same error . my intention is to get an output like the program written by @john using switch

Comment: @user1557910 That's not possible. In a `switch` statement, all `case` labels must be integer constants known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

are you assigning integer c to a or b? you should use = not == and put a or b in the left side of the assignment, not the right side. Like this:

```
if (c<5) {
    a=c;
}
```

otherwise, if a and b are integers **with an assigned value**, you can assign one or the other value to c, like:

```
if (c<5) {
    c=a;
}
```

keep in mind switch..case sentences in C can only switch between (compare) integer values (cases), that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: You have two variables a = 5 and b  = 7for example. You will use "=" for a become b: a = b. a will be 7. If you write b = a, b will be 5. You will use "==" in conditions like if(a==b), while(a==b), etc. Hope that you understand... :)